# Can I add a .travis.yml to all my previous commits in a repo?

Tags: git, github, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I've only just been getting into using Travis-CI for build automation and deploying.

Thing is, I only now realized that I could use Travis-CI as a way to automate builds on my other repositories, the 2 in question being  [abcm2ps](https://github.com/leesavide/abcm2ps) & [abcMIDI](https://github.com/leesavide/abcmidi).

I've gone to the task of tagging each of the commits I want there to be deployments on so there's a published release binary available for download.

My question is if it's possible for me to amend every commit to add a `.travis.yml` file, and how I'd go about doing that. Can anyone help?

Comment: It's possible if you're comfortable with the idea of rewriting your entire history, having to force-push every branch, and inconveniencing any other contributors — are you?

Comment: I'm ok with that, seeing as I'm the only contributor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your entire history to include the `.travis.yml` as follows. First, copy the file someplace outside of your repo (I'm going to call it `/src` for convenience). Then do:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'cp /src/.travis.yml .' -- --all
```

The tree-filter is run for each commit, and any new files it creates are added to the tree for that commit. In this case, we're copying the `.travis.yml` into the root of the repo for each commit. `--all` tells it to run on all visible refs (i.e. branches and tags). Afterwards, `/src/.travis.yml` isn't needed anymore and you can delete it.

Comment: That's perfect! :) it also means I can work on the build set up before I even commit it the first time, this is exactly what I needed! Thank you ^u^